# Regular expressions in python. Incorrect output

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if the string starts off with a number and then has 9 alpha-numeric characters. However, this returns yes instead of no. Why?

```
import re

if re.search(r'[0-9][0-9]{9}','92211sssff222'):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Comment: 9 of the same alphanumeric characters? Or 9 alphanumeric characters?

Comment: [It returns "no"](http://ideone.com/pFkEHu).

Comment: Based on your description, this is what I'd write: `re.search(r'^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{9}','92211sssff222')`

Comment: If any of the answer answered your question don't hesitate to accept it

Answer (score 1):

The alphanumeric range should be something like `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Also, since you want the string to *start* with this format, put the `^` (beginning of string) symbol, to match it exactly, otherwise a string such as `' !!!92211sssff222'` would match as well.

Fixed code:

```
import re

if re.search(r'^[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{9}','92211sssff222'):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this .Since you said it should start you have to use the cap symbol `^` which specifies the start

As per your regex you are matching ten continues number which can happen anywhere in the string

```
import re

if re.search(r'^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{9}','9sssssssff222'):
    print ("yes")
else:
    print ("no")

yes
```